# Is there a way to print the contents of the output window (visual studio)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, printing

While using visual studio 2017 community,
is there a way to *print* the contents of the output window?

(In SO, when searching "print" and output window, the poster usually mean "writing" to the output window. *This is not what I mean*. I mean literally printing to a physical printer what is already in the output window.

Comment: Not a direct solution, but I've always just used File -> New -> Text File and then copy + paste from output window, followed by printing the text document as an adequate workaround.

Comment: Thanks. By chance I happened to read that I can save the contents of the output window with Ctrl+S. Then I tried Ctrl+P and it seems this prints the contents of the output window. *I have not tried this yet* so I don't know it this is the answer

Comment: As a comment, I also found that I can save the output to a file and print it from there

Comment: That's a great option if you wanted to save an electronic copy anyway.  If all you care about is the paper copy, I would prefer using the clipboard, not the disk.